# table.row is not a function in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.9.4. On trying to use the datatable module I am getting the above error. Going through SO, I have seen a lot of people advising to use the uppercase `DataTable({})` instead of the lowercase `dataTable({})`, but still get the error.

```
var table = $("#example1").DataTable();
        $('#example1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var data = table.row(this).data();                
        });
```

Note this is an ASP.NET MVC Project

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
                                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)</th>
                                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName)</th>
                                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)</th>
                                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department)</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)</td>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleName)</td>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)</td>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department)</td>
                                              </tr>
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

Comment: Is your DataTable being initialized properly? Show us the table html

Comment: @EricGuan I have updated my question with the table markup

Comment: I am quite sure you have a cache problem. Be sure your browser is loading the correct version of your JS.  Even if your markup or something else was invalid, even if you get nasty alerts while initializing - you would still receive a table reference with an API you can work on.

Comment: @davidkonrad I launch my browser with Chrome's Dev tool always opened, so caching is not a problem

Comment: @kolexinfos, that does not matter if you not have caching turned off :) network -> disable cache -> reload

Comment: Did you try putting the declaration of `var table` inside your `click` function?

Comment: You need to make sure you're using DataTables 1.10. API method `row()` is available in **1.10+ only**.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com I am running version 1.9.4, I would try and update it if there is a nuget update and respond here

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery DataTables 1.9.4.

API method [`row()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29) is only available in jQuery DataTables 1.10+.

See if you can upgrade your library, it is backward compatible.

Comment: is this the same for rows mine is not finding it in the same verison

Comment: @csharpdudeni77, yes, it's the same for all API methods listed on [this page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/).